# Swift how to use container view and segmented control

Tags: ios, swift

I get a problem in using container view and segmented control to achieve switch views.I have put two container views in one view controller, and each of container view embed a new view(three view controller in the same UIViewController).

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ReportViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var containerTwoWeeks: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var containerToday: UIView! 

@IBOutlet weak var segUi: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var paymentPie: PieChartView!
@IBOutlet weak var incomePie: PieChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//        pieChartUpdate()
//        selectResultData()
}

@IBAction func segChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segUi.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        self.containerTwoWeeks.isHidden = false
        self.containerToday.isHidden = true
        break
    case 1:
        self.containerTwoWeeks.isHidden = true
        self.containerToday.isHidden = false
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}

func selectResultData() {
    resultLabel.attributedText = reportService.selectResultData()
}

func pieChartUpdate () {
    (too much code here, ignore it)
}

}
```

Everything works well until I called the method pieChartUpdate() or selectResultData() in vieDidLoad(),the error message as below

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I can switch the views without calling the pieChartUpdate() or selectResultData() method, so I really want to know the reason and solution.Hope someone could figure out this problem,thanks.

Comment: `resultLabel` is probably `nil`.

Comment: But the charts worked well before I want to swich views by segment, there is data in resultLabel and the chart came out,I wonder if there is some comflict in using two container view?

Comment: I tried resultLabel.text = "abc",but the same error come out,sounds like that I can not use resultLabel?

Comment: because it is `nil`, because you did not connect the outlet for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got very common mistake and error. But don't worry.

Check your full error message. There must be a clue what variable you are trying to access and getting nil (it might be `resultLabel`).

Then make sure the connection between storyboard and view controller for this variable is correct. You can try to remove and create it again if you don't get what is wrong.

If you need more help, please show us full error message.

Comment: Thanks guy,I think I found the problem,I define three view in the storyboard in the same viewController, so in the only viewController I can not connect the outlet  of any element(why?),I divided the three views into three controllers, then it worked, thanks anyway.